# Is $f(x, y) = 0x + 0y = 0$ the only implicit homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, implicit-function

Most of the time, implicits give you curves, for example $x^2 + y^2  = R^2$ or points $x^2 + y^2 = 0$.

The expression in the title is always satisfied so it spits out $\mathbb{R}^2$, is there any other expression that also spits out $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Are you asking if there is more than one function that takes the values zero everywhere?

Comment: Let us rephrase the problem as follows: given some $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, when is the intersection of the graph of $f$ with some constant plane homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?  Already, we see that any constant function will do, not just the zero function.  If we don't place restrictions on $f$, I fear we cannot make much progress.

Comment: I don't thinkk that rephrasing works. The set 0x +0y = C is the empty set for any C other than 0.

And you cannot put any cosntant in front of X or Y either, because then there's no way to make them constant anymore.

Comment: @user3716267 an implicit function is not really $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for example the circle equation cannot map anything to $r < -R^2$

Comment: I think you're interpreting my construction in a way I did not intend - the circle equation is indeed obtained by taking the intersection of $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ with some constant plane.

Comment: Yes but the preimage of $f$ is not the same as $f =0$ by definition $f=0$ is the set of all, and only of, the points that satisfy $f=0$. Thus in your consturction the set defined by the implicit is a circle, which is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Not every "implicit" in your original post is given in the form $f(x,y) = 0$.  If you only want to consider intersections with the zero plane, then sure, the other constant functions are ruled out.  It still seems unlikely that you will make much progress without restricting $f$ - set $f(x,y) = 0$ on some open disc, and equal to $1$ elsewhere.

Comment: The other implicits in my original point can eb turned into f(x,y) = 0, for example the circle $x^2 +y^2 - R^2 = 0$, in fact, by definition, every implicit can be turned into $f(x, y) = 0$

Comment: Yes, but you did not state them that way; I attempted to model my construction after your post (in fact, my original comment only considered intersections with the zero plane, and I modified it to be more consistent with what you had asked).  Again, I think you're getting caught up on specifics and missing the intended point: without further restrictions on $f$ (e.g. continuity), we cannot really make any progress on this.